# Not able to replace the file contents with sed command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to replace the pattern of the file from below command inside the shell script -

```
 "sed -i 's/start.datetime.*/start.datetime=$param_date 00:00:00/g'" conf.txt
```

But it gives below error -

```
./Test.sh: line 22: sed -i 's/start.datetime.*/start.datetime=2021-01-11 00:00:00/g': No such file or directory
```

However the very next line which is below gives required output -

```
echo `grep start.datetime conf.txt`
start.datetime=2020-12-01 00:00:00
```

I am not able to figure out why the sed not able to locate the file and replace the pattern.

Comment: Why do you have double quotes around the sed command?

Comment: Variable param_date is not visible otherwise to the sed.

Comment: You need to put them around the sed script, not the whole command. Like `sed -i "s/..."`

Comment: Use double quotes for parameter expansion or single quotes otherwise. Don't use both.